# Detecting presence of music in ambient sound

Tags: algorithm, audio, open-source, signal-processing, noise

I hoping to create an application that would listen to ambient sound and detect if music is being played. It is *not* important to identify the music being played; just detecting that some music is being played is enough.

I looked around for existing solutions but couldn't find any. Does anyone know algorithms that I can use to solve this problem? If source code is available, all the better.
I found are a couple of academic papers and implemented solutions suggested in them. But the results I obtained were not satisfactory.

PS: 
i) It would be a bonus if the algorithm is not computationally intensive; if algorithm is completely in time-domain that would be wonderful. ii) It is okay if the solution is not very accurate; occasional false-positives are okay.

Comment: Short answer: not really. Yes but not reliably. Short reason: musical sound is too dense. One short solution: search time domain for transient events and run calculations to see if there is a rhythm. You should expect all plausible solutions to be both computationally intensive and involve frequency domain. Maybe try asking on dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Radiodef - Thanks for pointing out dsp.stackexchange.com; I did not realize it existed.

Comment: Also, one person's music is another person's noise.

Comment: I think this would be easier if you tried to define what "music" is. Are you looking mainly for rhythm or melody? Looking for one would make the approach easier, but exclude portions of what most would call music.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that music is made of a bunch of chords instead of single pitch (like monophonic MIDI), multiple pitches at the same time (aka, the chords) may be a good candidate to be detected and differentiated from pure noise. Actually there is a very good [Harmony Progression Analyser software package](https://patterns.enm.bris.ac.uk/hpa-software-package) in which chords are detected based on a chromagram. Hope it helps.

Comment: Drummers would deny this definition of music.